# issue in deleting role in Zizaco/entrust

Tags: laravel, entrust

Iam trying to delete a role

```
$role = Role::findOrFail(1);
$role->delete();
```

I got the following error

```
FatalErrorException in Model.php line 945:
Class name must be a valid object or a string
```

in vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/commands/MigrationCommand.php on line 86

```
$usersTable  = Config::get('auth.providers.users.table');
$userModel   = Config::get('auth.providers.users.model');
```

Role model class

```
namespace App\Models;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{
       protected $fillable =  ['name', 'display_name', 'isActive','description', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

}
```

Comment: can you post the content of the Role class?

Comment: I posted it in an answer dialogue

Comment: ok, but it's better to edit the original posting/the question and add it there - so that other people can see it too  - maybe they have an idea.

Comment: And: check out this issue if this is your problem eventually. https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/500

Comment: no it doesnot help

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

Find the file: 
vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/Entrust/Traits/EntrustRoleTrait.php

Replace

**Line 51:**  ... `Config::get('auth.model')` ...

with

**Line 51:** ... `Config::get('auth.providers.users.model')` ...

Comment: core packages must not be changes. Your changes might replace on your next update.

Answer (score 0):

Its not good practice to update anything in core packages because in case you update your package, this change will be replace, instead override that function by adding this in your `App\Role.php`

```
/**
 * Many-to-Many relations with the user model.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Config::get('auth.providers.users.model'), Config::get('entrust.role_user_table'),Config::get('entrust.role_foreign_key'),Config::get('entrust.user_foreign_key'));
   // return $this->belongsToMany(Config::get('auth.model'), Config::get('entrust.role_user_table'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Tarunn. If you want code simplicity....

```
use App\User;

/**
* Many-to-Many relations with the user model.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
*/

public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```